# Resetting qt5 application font to sensible default

Tags: qt, fonts

So my QT5 applications (OK, that's only OpenSCAD) now have a huge font. So huge actually that I can only read three words on the screen (“File”, “Edit”, “Editor” for the OpenSCAD menus). (I don't know which change caused that: I did not open it for some time).

I tried installing `qt5ct` to reset fonts to a sensible default value... except that this tool uses itself qt5 (that's logical, if a bit unsafe) and so is also unreadable.

Which configuration file should I try editing to make the thing usable again?

Info that might be useful: the machine is Debian testing; I don't know the exact QT version info since `qt5ct` does not recognize the `--version` switch.

*Edit to add:* although fonts are huge, icons are normal size, so this is probably not a screen resolution problem, but really a font problem.

Comment: Not sure, but you might want to have a look at the file `~/.config/qt5ct/qt5ct.conf` .  On the box I'm currently working on that file controls the basic Qt GUI config.

Comment: I had some success setting `QT_FONT_DPI=144`. Although this is an opaque “solution”: why it suddenly stopped working, and which exact value I am supposed to put in there, remain a mystery.